# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check Laravel and Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, cross-domain, laravel-5.1

I have a REST api made in Laravel 5.1 hosted in a remote server. Now, I', trying to consume that API from another website (that I have in local).

In Laravel I set the required lines to send the CORS headers. I also tested the API using Postman and everything seems to be ok!

**In the Frontend**

Then, in the website I sent the POST request using ajax, with this code:

```
var url="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/apiLocation";
var data=$("#my-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    headers: { 'token': 'someAPItoken that I need to send'},
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                });
```

Buy then I get this error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/apiLocation.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

**In the Backend**

In the API I set this (using a Laravel Middleware to set the headers):

```
return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

So, I'm confused about where is exactly the problem.

1. In the server? but then why with Postman work fine?
2. Is in the Ajax call? so, then what should I add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your backend code must include some explicit handling for `OPTIONS` requests that sends a `200` response with just the configured headers; for example:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
    return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
}
```

The server-side code also must send an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header that includes the name of the `token` request header your frontend code is sending:

```
-> header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'token')
```

> but then why with Postman work fine?

Postman isn’t a web app and isn’t bound by same-origin  restrictions placed on web apps by browsers to block them from making cross-origin requests. Postman is a browser bolt-on for convenience of testing requests in the same way they could be made outside the browser using `curl` or whatever from the command line. Postman can freely make cross-origin requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS in contrast explains how browsers block web apps from making cross-origin requests but also how you can un-block browsers from doing that by configuring your backend to send the right CORS headers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests explains why the browser is sending that `OPTIONS` request your backend needs to handle.